# syntax error in shell script jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am using jenkins, so iam trying to execute below code in '**execute shell**'

**Below is the script:**

```
ssh user@prod-server
cd /myfolder
pwd

if [ ! -d myproj ]; then
  git clone http://prod-server/bbb/myproj.git
else
  cd myproj
  pwd
  git pull
fi
```

In '**execute shell**', iam trying as below but getting syntax errors while trying to build:

```
ssh prod-server  'cd /myfolder && pwd && if [ ! -d myproj ]; then git clone http://prod-server/bbb/myproj.git else cd myproj  pwd  git pull  fi'
```

**Here is the syntax error:**

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

So, please tell me what to modify?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax errors are to be expected, as the single commands in the else tree are not really separated. How should your shell (bash I presume) know where a command starts or ends? Try the following:

```
ssh prod-server  'cd /myfolder && pwd && if [ ! -d myproj ]; then git clone http://prod-server/bbb/myproj.git else cd myproj; pwd; git pull; fi'
```

Alternatively, you can also separate them by `&&` instead of `;` and thus execute the next command only when the former one succeeded.

Comment: Answer by Ralf is correct (so I won't make another competing answer). As an alternative, you can also consider a "here doc" syntax, described in second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine?lq=1